# Sum under main diagonal in julia

Tags: julia

How to sum under the main diagonal without using main diagonal in matrix, in `julia`?

I was using `sum=tril(a)-1` but it doesn't work in `julia`.

I know I need a mask but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for the [`LinearAlgebra` module](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/), which is part of the standard library and contains a `tril` function:

```
julia> using LinearAlgebra

julia> A = ones(5, 5)
5×5 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0

julia> tril(A, -1)
5×5 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0

julia> sum(tril(A, -1))
10.0
```

Answer (score 6):

[`tril`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/#LinearAlgebra.tril) function is in the Linear Algebra standard library. To use it, you need to import the `LinearAlgebra` module. `tril` takes a second optional argument to specify where you want to start the lower triangular part. You can set it to -1 in order not to take the main diagonal.

```
using LinearAlgebra

A = rand(5, 5)
lowerA = tril(A, -1)
println(sum(lowerA))
```

You might also want to take a look at lazy lower triangular view constructors such as `LowerTriangular` or `OneUnitLowerTriangular`.